# Css div overflow hidden behind parent border

Tags: html, css

I have a little CSS problem.

I sketched the problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/0g4b23hp/

The css:

```
a {
    padding: 7px 10px 5px 10px;
    background: #FF0000;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.bottom-1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that in **all browsers** the 2 buttons get across the black border and that the corners have radius 0px; But I don't get it right;

I already tried to make the `padding-bottom:50px` and `overflow:hidden` but didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean `.bottom-1{bottom:-4px;}`?

Comment: What do you mean by "get across the black border" ?

Comment: You need to rewrite this question. It make 0 sense based on the example you provided.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain it enough and I should have added an image with the result, will do it in the future; thanks anyway!

Comment: @Pangloss your option also looks nice, thanks for your answer I'm also going to use this for other buttons! I'm not able to upvote you yet; but thank you very much you also helped me!

Comment: @Thempower I suggest you invest ten minutes reading this article. I promise you won't regret it.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: @Padawan thanks, I bookmarked that site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is that in all browsers the 2 buttons get across the black border and that the corners have radius 0px;

I think will do what you want.

```css
a {
    padding: 7px 10px 5px 10px;
    background: #FF0000;
    /* REMOVED
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    */
}
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
}
.bottom-1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    transform:translateY(50%);
}
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div class="bottom-1">
            <div class="background2"></div> <a href="#">Action 1</a>
 <a href="#">Action 2</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```